# Changing the cell name

Tags: python

I have a file that contains the following:

| Name |
| --- |
| ABCD0145 |
| ABCD1445 |
| ABCD0998 |

And I'm trying to write a cod that read every row and change the name to the following format:

| Name |
| --- |
| ABCD_145 |
| ABCD_1445 |
| ABCD_998 |

keeping in mind that it should maintain letters (ABCD), add (_) after it and then add the numbers

if there is a zero such as (`"ABCD**0**145"`), it should remove it to be (`"ABCD_145"`).

Comment: Okay, that's straightforward enough. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: I have tried `dataframe["Name"][0].replace('0', '_', 1)` to works if there are more than one zero value at least before last element

Comment: Can you elaborate more? If you can write it in a code format so I can try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this regx

```
  df['Name2'] = df.Name.str.replace('[0-9]+', '') + '_' + df.Name.str.replace('([A-Z])+', '').str.lstrip("0")
```

- Capital A-Z

  df.Name.str.replace('[0-9]+', '')
- Numbers without 0

  df.Name.str.replace('([A-Z])+', '').str.lstrip("0")
- join them with '-' in middle

### To get back original

```
df['Name3']  = (df.Name2.str.replace('[0-9]+', '') +  df.Name2.str.replace('([A-Z])+', '').str.zfill(5)).str.replace('_','')

Out[92]: 
       Name      Name2     Name3
0  ABCD0145   ABCD_145  ABCD0145
1  ABCD1445  ABCD_1445  ABCD1445
2  ABCD0998   ABCD_998  ABCD0998
3  ABCD0052    ABCD_52  ABCD0052
4  ABCD1800  ABCD_1800  ABCD1800
```

Comment: thank you Surjit for your help. I have tried your code and it give me: 'list' object has no attribute 'Name'

however, my list has Name header in the first cell\

Comment: there may be space in your column name

Comment: there is no space I have checked that

Comment: what does this gives you ?       df.columns

Comment: The code worked fine thank you but there is one problem, for rows with ABCD1800 it gave me ABCD_18. it deleted the last zeros. I have tried to delete the zero from df.Name.str.replace('([A-Z])+', '') it worked but again it messes rows with ABCD0052 to be ABCD_0052

Comment: what was the issue? or what was messing

Comment: and I want the opposite (start from output then aiming for inputs) it should be similar?

Comment: then you assign it back to name column, see the updated answer

Comment: the updated answer is working fine if I want from (ABCD0011) to (ABCD_11) but if the objective was the opposite starting from (ABCD_11) to (ABCD0011). the code will not change that much right?

Answer (score 2):

With single regex replacement:

```
df['Name'].str.replace(r'(\D)0?([1-9])', r'\1_\2')
```

- `\D` - non-digit character
- `0?` - match optional `0` (if occurs)
- `[1-9]` - match any digit in range from `1` to `9`

---

```
0     ABCD_145
1    ABCD_1445
2     ABCD_998
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name': ['ABCD0145', 'ABCD1445', 'ABCD0998', 'ABCD0052']})

def transform_name(data):
  data = data.replace('0', '') 
  print(data)
  modified_data = ''
  if(data[4]=='0'):
    modified_data = data[:4] + '_' + data[5:]
  else:
    modified_data = data[:4] + '_' + data[4:]
  return modified_data

df['ModifiedName'] = df['Name'].apply(transform_name)
df
```

The above function will generate output as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Sadman

I have tried your code, and it gave me error: (list indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Comment: if the data frame column contains all strings, then there shouldn't be this error. Can you tell which line gives an error?

Comment: my data name is df 
and the error in the line ---> 9 df['ModifiedName'] = df['Name'].apply(transform_name)

Comment: I think you have a list of strings, not a dataframe column of strings. Right? In that case, please convert that list of strings to a pandas dataframe. I've modified the answer code, please check that!

Comment: It works now! thank you. but for rows with ABCD0052 it gives ABCD_0052 and I want ABCD_52 only without zoros

Comment: I've further updated the answer to reflect multiple zeros after 'ABCD'. Hope now it will work as a solution. However, note that this approach will not work if there is a zero at the very end of the string, since the zeros are replaced with blanks at the beginning.

Comment: How can we include zeros at the far end? such as ABCD1800 to be ABCD_1800

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over each row, using **`foo`** to replace 0 values or insert a new underscore character at the 4th index of the array:

```
def foo(s):
    if s[4] == '0':
         s = s.replace('0', '', 1) 
         return foo(s)
    else:
         s = list(s)
         s.insert(4, '_')
         s = "".join(s)
    return s 

#...
>>> df
       Name         other    id
0  ABCD0145  217335855539  0145
1  ABCD1445  196754871428  1445
2  ABCD0998  200413254970  0998
3  ABCD0052  222270482326  0052
>>> df["Name"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: foo(x))
>>> df["Name"]
0     ABCD_145
1    ABCD_1445
2     ABCD_998
3      ABCD_52
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Did you try this? There are multiple bugs I can see here...