# Conver string from `ABCD0011` to `ABCD_11`

Tags: python

I have the following CSV file:

```
ABCD0011
ABCD1404
ABCD1255
```

There are many such rows in the CSV file which I want to convert as follows:

| Input | Expected Output | Actual Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD0011 | ABCD_11_0 | ABCD_0011_0 |
| ABCD1404 | ABCD_1404_0 | ABCD_144_0 |
| ABCD1255 | ABCD_1255_0 | ABCD_1255_0 |

Basically, it takes the zeros after the letters and replace it with an underscore ("_").

#### Code

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')    
df.A = df.A.str.replace('[0-9]+', '')+'_'+df.A.str.replace('([A-Z])+', '')+'_0'
```

#### Actual Output and Issues

I got the values that are without leading zeros correctly converted like

- from `ABCD1255` to `ABCD_1255_0`.

But for values with leading zeros it failed, example:

- from `ABCD0011` to `ABCD_0011_0`. Did not change the format.

Even for values with zeros inside it failed, like

- from `ABCD1404` to `ABCD_144_0`. It deleted the zero in the middle.

#### Question

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do all rows start with 'ABCD'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979972/changing-the-cell-name/

Answer (score 2):

If we know the input strings will always be eight characters, with the first four being letter and the second set of four being a number, we could:

```
>>> s = "ABCD0011"
>>> f"{s[:4]}_{int(s[4:])}_0"
'ABCD_11_0'
```

If we *don't* know the lengths for sure, we can use `re.sub` with a lambda to transform two different matching groups.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)', lambda m: f"{m.group(1)}_{int(m.group(2))}_0", s)
'ABCD_11_0'
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)', lambda m: f"{m.group(1)}_{int(m.group(2))}_0", 'A709')
'A_709_0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the apparent requirement for a dataframe, this is how you could parse the file and generate the strings you need. Uses *re*. Does not use *numpy* and/or *pandas*

```
import re

FILENAME = 'well.csv'
PATTERN = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)$')

with open(FILENAME) as csv_data:
    next(csv_data) # skip header(s)
    for line in csv_data:
        if m := PATTERN.search(line):
            print(f'{m.group(1)}_{int(m.group(2))}_0')
```

This will work for the data shown in the question. Other data structures may cause this to fail.

**Output:**

```
ABCD_11_0
ABCD_1404_0
ABCD_1255_0
```